# Unable to get top frequent words for multiple files

Tags: java, file, apache-tika, stop-words, word-frequency

Hi i have stored 3 html files in my htmlfiles folder, for these files extracted text using tika and stored it into text files in htmltextfiles folder. for each text file in htmltextfiles folder i removed stopwords and displayed top 10 frequently occuring words.
My htmltextfiles contains:

```
java.txt file contains:This is Java Program written in java

Php.txt file contains:This is Php Program written in Php

.net.txt file contains:This is .net Program written in .net
```

Below is my java program

```
public class FrequencyCount {
    int[][] table = new int[4][1000000];
    TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>(
            Collections.reverseOrder());
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FrequencyCount freq = new FrequencyCount();
    BufferedReader br = null;

    String[] stopwords = { "a", "about", "above", "above", "across",
            "after", "afterwards", "again", "against", "all", "almost",
            "alone", "along", "already", "also", "although", "always",
            "am", "among", "amongst", "amoungst", "amount", "an", "and",
            "another", "any", "anyhow", "anyone", "anything", "anyway",
            "anywhere", "are", "around", "as", "at", "back", "be",
            "became", "because", "become", "becomes", "becoming", "been",
            "before", "beforehand", "behind", "being", "below", "beside",
            "besides", "between", "beyond", "bill", "both", "bottom",
            "but", "by", "call", "can", "cannot", "cant", "co", "con",
            "could", "couldnt", "cry", "de", "describe", "detail", "do",
            "done", "down", "due", "during", "each", "eg", "eight",
            "either", "eleven", "else", "elsewhere", "empty", "enough",
            "etc", "even", "ever", "every", "everyone", "everything",
            "everywhere", "except", "few", "fifteen", "fify", "fill",
            "find", "fire", "first", "five", "for", "former", "formerly",
            "forty", "found", "four", "from", "front", "full", "further",
            "get", "give", "go", "had", "has", "hasnt", "have", "he",
            "hence", "her", "here", "hereafter", "hereby", "herein",
            "hereupon", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how",
            "however", "hundred", "ie", "if", "in", "inc", "indeed",
            "interest", "into", "is", "it", "its", "itself", "keep",
            "last", "latter", "latterly", "least", "less", "ltd", "made",
            "many", "may", "me", "meanwhile", "might", "mill", "mine",
            "more", "moreover", "most", "mostly", "move", "much", "must",
            "my", "myself", "name", "namely", "neither", "never",
            "nevertheless", "next", "nine", "no", "nobody", "none",
            "noone", "nor", "not", "nothing", "now", "nowhere", "of",
            "off", "often", "on", "once", "one", "only", "onto", "or",
            "other", "others", "otherwise", "our", "ours", "ourselves",
            "out", "over", "own", "part", "per", "perhaps", "please",
            "put", "rather", "re", "same", "see", "seem", "seemed",
            "seeming", "seems", "serious", "several", "she", "should",
            "show", "side", "since", "sincere", "six", "sixty", "so",
            "some", "somehow", "someone", "something", "sometime",
            "sometimes", "somewhere", "still", "such", "system", "take",
            "ten", "than", "that", "the", "their", "them", "themselves",
            "then", "thence", "there", "thereafter", "thereby",
            "therefore", "therein", "thereupon", "these", "they", "thickv",
            "thin", "third", "this", "those", "though", "three", "through",
            "throughout", "thru", "thus", "to", "together", "too", "top",
            "toward", "towards", "twelve", "twenty", "two", "un", "under",
            "until", "up", "upon", "us", "very", "via", "was", "we",
            "well", "were", "what", "want", "wants", "whatever", "when",
            "whence", "whenever", "where", "whereafter", "whereas",
            "whereby", "wherein", "whereupon", "wherever", "whether",
            "which", "while", "whither", "who", "whoever", "whole", "whom",
            "whose", "why", "will", "with", "within", "without", "would",
            "yet", "you", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves", "1",
            "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "1.", "2.", "3.",
            "4.", "5.", "6.", "11", "7.", "8.", "9.", "12", "13", "14",
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
            "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X",
            "Y", "Z", "terms", "CONDITIONS", "conditions", "values",
            "interested.", "care", "sure", ".", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%",
            "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "{", "}", "[", "]", ":", ";", ",",
            "<", ".", ">", "/", "?", "_", "-", "+", "=", "a", "b", "c",
            "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
            "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
            "contact", "grounds", "buyers", "tried", "said,", "plan",
            "value", "principle.", "forces", "sent:", "is,", "was", "like",
            "discussion", "tmus", "diffrent.", "layout", "area.", "thanks",
            "thankyou", "hello", "bye", "rise", "fell", "fall", "psqft.",
            "http://", "km", "miles" };
    File dir = new File("C://htmlfiles");
    File listDir[] = dir.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listDir.length; i++) 
    {
        String file = listDir[i].toString();
        File file1 = new File(file);
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file1);
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(10 * 1024 * 1024);
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        parser.parse(input, handler, metadata);
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new Field("contents", handler.toString(), Field.Store.NO,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        String path = "C://htmltextfiles".concat("/").concat(listDir[i].getName()).concat(".txt");
        File file2 = new File(path);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file2.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(handler.toString());
        bw.close();
    }

    try 
    {
        File dir1 = new File("C://htmltextfiles");
        File listDir1[] = dir1.listFiles();
        for (int k = 0; k < listDir1.length; k++) 
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(listDir1[k].getAbsolutePath())));
            String fileline = br.readLine();
            while (fileline != null) 
            {
                if (fileline.length() > 0) 
                {
                    String[] sArr = fileline.split(" ");
                    for (String s : sArr)
                    {
                        int flag = 1;
                        for (int j = 0; j < stopwords.length; j++)
                        {
                            String s1 = s.toLowerCase();
                            if (s1.equals(stopwords[j]))
                            {
                                flag = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        if (flag != 0)
                        {
                            if (s.trim().length() > 0) 
                            {
                                try 
                                {
                                    freq.add(freq.trimStr(s));
                                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                fileline = br.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println("Keywords for file:" + listDir1[k].getName());
            Set<Integer> set = freq.map.keySet();
            for (Integer x : set) {
                System.out.println(freq.map.get(x) + " found " + x
                        + " times");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}

public String trimStr(String s) {
    if (s.toUpperCase().equals(s.toLowerCase())) {
        return s;
    }
    s = s.toLowerCase().trim();

    if (s.endsWith("'s")) {
        s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 2);
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = s.length() - 1;
    char[] cArr = s.toCharArray();

    while (!(cArr[i] >= 65 && cArr[i] <= 90)
            && !(cArr[i] >= 97 && cArr[i] <= 122)) {
        i++;
    }

    while (!(cArr[j] >= 65 && cArr[j] <= 90)
            && !(cArr[j] >= 97 && cArr[j] <= 122)) {
        j--;
    }

    return s.substring(i, j + 1);
}

public int[] hash(String s) {
    int h1 = hash1(s);
    int h2 = hash2(s);
    int h3 = hash3(s);
    int h4 = hash4(s);

    int[] res = new int[] { h1, h2, h3, h4 };
    return res;
}

public int hash1(String x) {
    char ch[] = x.toCharArray();
    int i, sum;
    for (sum = 0, i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
        sum += ch[i];
    return sum % 1000000;
}

public int hash2(String s) {
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        h = 31 * h + s.charAt(i);
    }
    h = h % 1000000;
    if (h < 0) {
        h = -h;
    }
    return h;
}

public int hash3(String s) {
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        h = 17 * h + s.charAt(i);
    }
    h = h % 1000000;
    if (h < 0) {
        h = -h;
    }
    return h;
}

public int hash4(String s) {
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        h = 11 * h + s.charAt(i);
    }
    h = h % 1000000;
    if (h < 0) {
        h = -h;
    }
    return h;
}

public void add(String s) {

    int[] h = hash(s);
    table[0][h[0]] = table[0][h[0]] + 1;
    table[1][h[1]] = table[1][h[1]] + 1;
    table[2][h[2]] = table[2][h[2]] + 1;
    table[3][h[3]] = table[3][h[3]] + 1;
    int r = Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(table[0][h[0]], table[1][h[1]]),
            table[2][h[2]]), table[3][h[3]]);
    boolean add = true;
    List<String> list = map.get(r);
    if (list == null) {
        if (map.size() == 10) {
            Integer lastKey = map.lastKey();
            if (lastKey.intValue() > r) {
                add = false;
            } else {
                map.remove(lastKey);
            }
        }
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    if (add) {
        list.add(s);
        map.put(r, list);
        if (r > 1) {
            list = map.get(r - 1);
            if (list != null) {
                if (list.size() == 1) {
                    map.remove(r - 1);
                } else {
                    list.remove(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public int count(String s) {
    int[] h = hash(s);
    int a = table[0][h[0]];
    int b = table[1][h[1]];
    int c = table[2][h[2]];
    int d = table[3][h[3]];
    int r = Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(a, b), c), d);
    return r;
}
}
```

For this code I am getting below output

```
Keywords for file:java.htm.txt
[java] found 2 times
Keywords for file:php.htm.txt
[java] found 2 times
[php] found 2 times
Keywords for file:.net.html.txt
[java] found 2 times
[php] found 2 times
[.net] found 2 times
```

The problem is that the keywords for one file are adding to the next file keywords, My intention is to get the below output

```
    Keywords for file:java.htm.txt
    [java] found 2 times
    Keywords for file:php.htm.txt
    [php] found 2 times
    Keywords for file:.net.html.txt
    [.net] found 2 times
```

Can anyone please suggest me how to achieve this, i have tried in many ways but not getting my required output, please help me..
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your map as static and clear your map after for loop.

```
    for (int k = 0; k < listDir1.length; k++) 
    {
        map.clear();
    ..............
    ......
    }
```

Comment: Thanks its working, one more doubt i want to list all this filename along with keywords in json format, is it possible because i want to store this in mongodb

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same datastructure for frequency (freq) for all the files, as I see you should have one different instance of freq per file, just arround this line:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(listDir1[k].getAbsolutePath())));
```

add this one:

```
freq = new FrequencyCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using common `map` for all files, but what you require is per file. Initialize map inside file iteration loop:

```
for (int k = 0; k < listDir1.length; k++)
        {
map = new TreeMap...
..
}
```

or after printing `map` values, clear it

Comment: Just cleaning the map might not work, there are other parts of the FrequencyCount that are not shown and could lead to errors if the rest of the datastructure is not cleaned.

Comment: In that case, making new `FrequencyCount` instance would make more sense.